# Git submodules from svn-externals

Tags: git, svn, svn-externals

I'm trying to bring a project from svn to git. In the project, I have 2 externals. I've made 2 folders for the externals and clone them in each folder. After, I've cloned the project itself. So, I've got 3 repo : 1 for the project and 2 for the externals inside the project's folder. To link the project with his externals, I need to add them in submodules with the command : `git submodule add`. For example, my project is in the folder : `C:/hubert/compo1` and the 2 externals are : `C:/hubert/compo1/external1` and `C:/hubert/compo1/external2`

```
git submodule add C:/hubert/compo1 C:/hubert/compo1/external1
git submodule add C:/hubert/compo1 C:/hubert/compo1/external2
```

After adding them, I do the : `git submodule init` and it gives me the error : `fatal: No url found for submodule path 'external1' in .gitmodules`.

---

Can someone help me ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my error, my commands of submodule add aren't correct. Here's what I've used : `git submodule C:/hubert/compo1/external1`